# sqlsrv_fetch_array in php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I try to retrieve a single row data without looping, somehow i couldn't echo the result that I want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE [TxId] = '?'";
    $params = array($TxId);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$status = $row["Status"];
echo "status: ".$status."<br>";
```

Is SQL server and Mysql different in retrieve single row record?

Thanks!

Comment: no, it is not. `var_dump($stmt);`

Comment: are you sure you query selects only one row?

Comment: Never used sqlsrv.But i believe that you should try  $row[0]["Status"]